# How can I sort the characters of a single string with Pointer Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers

I want to create a program in C programming that can sort the characters of a single string and sort the list of strings in alphabetical order. Sadly, while I got the program to sort the list, it won't sort the individual characters in each part of the string. Here is the code I have now:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<string.h>   
#include<ctype.h>   
#include<stdlib.h> 
 
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20  
#define TOTAL_STRING 10  

int main()    
{    
    int wordNum,i,j;  
    char *pointer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];   
    char p, *strlist;  
  
    printf("How many words will you enter (must be at most 21):");  
    scanf("%d", &wordNum);  
    getchar();  
    printf("You will print %d words\n", wordNum);  
     
    if(wordNum<=MAX_STRING_LENGTH){  
        for(i=0;i<wordNum;i++){  
            j=0;  
            strlist=malloc(TOTAL_STRING*sizeof(char));  
            p=getchar();  
            while(p!='\n'){  
                *(strlist+j)=p;  
                j++;  
                p=getchar();  
            }  
            if(p=='\n'){  
                strlist[j]='\0';  
            }  
            pointer[i]=strlist;  
        } 
    } 
     
    for(i=0;i<wordNum-1;i++){ 
        for(j=i+1;j<wordNum;j++){ 
            if(strcmp(pointer[i], pointer[j])>0){ 
                char *temp = pointer[i]; 
                pointer[i] = pointer[j]; 
                pointer[j] = temp; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
     
    printf("Words now sorted:\n");
 
    for(i=0;i<wordNum;i++){ 
        printf("%s\n", pointer[i]); 
    } 
     
    printf("Bye!");  
       
    return 0;    
}
```

Input : geeksforgeeks
Expected outcome : eeeefggkkorss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Re: `while (p != '\n')` this loop is susceptible to buffer overflow. You have essentially re-implemented `gets` - a function so poorly designed it was removed from the standard library (see: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965)). Advice: use larger buffers and use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (see also: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2505965)). Both sorts can be handled by [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you realized that your code does not contain a function to sort the characters in each individual character array or if you were looking for help in how to create such a sorting function.  In either case, following is a refactored version of your code that includes a character sort function and the execution of that function within the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20
#define TOTAL_STRING 10

void sortString(char *work)         /* Added character array sorting function    */
{
    char temp;
    int sorted = 1;

    while (sorted)
    {
        sorted = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(work) - 1); i++)
        {
            if (work[i] > work[i+1])
            {
                sorted = 1;
                temp = work[i];
                work[i] = work[i + 1];
                work[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int wordNum,i,j;
    char *pointer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char p, *strlist;

    printf("How many words will you enter (must be at most 21): ");
    scanf("%d", &wordNum);
    getchar();
    printf("You will print %d word(s)\n", wordNum);

    if(wordNum<=MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
    {
        for(i=0; i<wordNum; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter string: ");       /* Added for user look and feel */
            j=0;
            strlist=malloc(TOTAL_STRING*sizeof(char));
            p=getchar();
            while(p!='\n')
            {
                *(strlist+j)=p;
                j++;
                p=getchar();
            }
            if(p=='\n')
            {
                strlist[j]='\0';
            }
            pointer[i]=strlist;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < wordNum; i++)       /* Sort the characters within each entered string   */
        sortString(pointer[i]);

    for(i=0; i<wordNum-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<wordNum; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(pointer[i], pointer[j])>0)
            {
                char *temp = pointer[i];
                pointer[i] = pointer[j];
                pointer[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Words now sorted:\n");

    for(i=0; i<wordNum; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pointer[i]);
    }

    printf("Bye!\n");                   /* Added newline for aesthetics */

    return 0;
}
```

Following are the key points.

- The missing function to sort the characters within each individual character array was added.
- After the entry of one or more sets of text/strings, a "for" loop is used to call the new function to sort the characters within each entered string.

With that bit of refactoring, following were a couple of tests.  The first one being the entry of the string noted in your issue/question and a second test with multiple string entries.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Stringlist/bin/Release$ ./Stringlist 
How many words will you enter (must be at most 21): 1
You will print 1 word(s)
Enter string: geeksforgeeks
Words now sorted:
eeeefggkkorss
Bye!
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Stringlist/bin/Release$ ./Stringlist 
How many words will you enter (must be at most 21): 2
You will print 2 word(s)
Enter string: greatest
Enter string: least
Words now sorted:
aeegrstt
aelst
Bye!
```

Again, I was not sure if the type of help needed was in reference as to why the entered string(s) were not having their characters sorted, or if help was needed in constructing a sort function.  Either way go ahead and review the refactored code.  Also, it probably would be good to delve more into some "C" tutorial literature as it pertains to character arrays and functions.